# Are stock symbols unique between US and Canada?

Tags: stock-markets

I am putting all the stock symbols in the database and would like to know if the symbols are unique between Amex/Nasdaq/NYSE/TSE (Toronto stock exchange)

Answer (score 9):

Stock symbols are issued by the exchange that the stock is listing on.

If a company is listed on multiple exchanges, their stock may or may not have the same symbol across those exchanges.

Comment: Example: DHC. Had some fun tracking it down. Deer Horn is a mining company with a ticker of DHC but if you try to find it by DHC you usually find something else.

Answer (score 8):

Not across the international border. E.g. **AC** is Air Canada on the TSX and Associated Capital Group on the NYSE.